# Sending on behalf of multiple business from one number

Tags: twilio

My company has been using Twilio for years and we've only used one toll free number. Our customers are other businesses and we use Twilio to send SMS texts on behalf of those other businesses. I've just been told this will not be a possible set up anymore with all of the new verification stuff put in place. Twilio Support told me I now need a phone number for each business that we send texts on behalf of. Does anyone else use Twilio in a similar manner? Meaning do you send texts for multiple businesses on the same number? If so how did you handle the Toll Free Verification process? Or are using a local number or short code?

Answer (score 2):

Tollfree numbers are $1 per month, if that is the best solution, why not just add a few more? And, I think, whether tollfree or local number, the requirements are the same. Short Codes also have similar requirements which are explained on this page about ["Allowing end users to opt-out of individual parts of a multiple program short code campaigns."](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134787-Allowing-end-users-to-opt-out-of-individual-parts-of-a-multiple-program-short-code-campaigns)

I am finding the A2P 10DLC process to be confusing and have read through it multiple times - probably because the requirements are changing and being implemented fast. Bravo for anything to reduce spam and junk SMS.

The table ["Understanding your ISV type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv#identify-your-isv-type)" is helpful to align your view of your company with how Twilio views your company.

Note this [suggested architecture](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv#2-overview-of-isv-architectures-for-a2p-10dlc):

> Please note, however, that these different architectures are NOT all
> equally viable going forward, given the requirements for A2P 10DLC
> registration that will enforced as of the Summer of 2023. In general,
> patterns #3, #5 and #6 below will not be viable for A2P 10DLC
> registration, and any clients using these architectures currently will
> need to migrate to patterns #1, #2 or #4. Of these latter three, we
> suggest that pattern #1 will prove the most useful in the longer term.
> These points will be explained below with reference to specific
> patterns.

Comment: It is best solution but for us it comes down to cost and management. We will have to purchase 500-600 numbers. So that's the reason we are looking for an alternative.